# Constructing an XML with JAXB and multiple same sub-elements

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I've build a Java class based on a schema file and now I'm building a program to build an actual XML file based on the generated class and the schema underneath it. There is a part where multiple sub-elements are allowed, for example:

```
<entry>
    <methods>
        <method type="walking"/>
        <method type="running"/>
        <method type="cycling"/>
    </methods>
</entry>
```

User input is required to enter the `<method>` element until a `-` is given to end the list. However, when I gather the inputs to be added the to list the list only includes the last method I've given, for example:

```
Enter a method (- to finish): walking
Enter a method (- to finish): running
Enter a method (- to finish): cycling
Enter a method (- to finish): -
```

Results in a:

```
    <methods>
        <method type="cycling"/>
        <method type="cycling"/>
        <method type="cycling"/>
    </methods>
```

This is my code for gathering the methods:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

entry.methods methods = new entry.methods();
entry.methods.method method = new entry.methods.method();

while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter a method (- to finish): ");
    String given = input.next();
    if (given.equals("-")) {
        break;
    }
    method.setType(given);
    methods.getMethod().add(method);
}

entry.setMethods(methods);
```

To my understanding, the `add(method)` is supposed to add a new entry to the end of the list, but instead it somehow seems to be replacing all the entries given with the last one. I'm walking in circles with this issue even though the problem is probably something very simple. I'll paste the classes here and such if required to solve problem, but yes, I'm quite new to Java / JAXB - and yes, this is related to a school project so I apologize if the set-up presented is strange or explained oddly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you overwrite the method with each iteration. try moving this line: `entry.methods.method method = new entry.methods.method();`
inside the loop.

Comment: That solved it! I guessed as far as the problem being something as simple as this, but couldn't see that being the issue.